# App runs but : - E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

I have mediaplayer app, the app runs fine on API level 20+ .. i mean its working on Android Pie.
But it wont run on Android 4.4.4 KitKat: The reason was this below:

```
musicOne.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                finish();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
```

So i decided to remove this line and then app worked fine but then this new error started coming :
App Works!! but errors

```
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/MediaPlayer: Don't send intent. msg.arg1 = 0, msg.arg2 = 0
E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
I/MediaPlayer: Don't send intent. msg.arg1 = 0, msg.arg2 = 0
E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
I/MediaPlayer: Don't send intent. msg.arg1 = 0, msg.arg2 = 0
E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
I/MediaPlayer: Don't send intent. msg.arg1 = 0, msg.arg2 = 0
E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
I/MediaPlayer: Don't send intent. msg.arg1 = 0, msg.arg2 = 0
E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
I/MediaPlayer: Don't send intent. msg.arg1 = 0, msg.arg2 = 0
E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
I/MediaPlayer: Don't send intent. msg.arg1 = 0, msg.arg2 = 0
E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
I/MediaPlayer: Don't send intent. msg.arg1 = 0, msg.arg2 = 0
E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@420f74c0 time:4462603
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
    Connection attempt already in progress
    Activity resumed, time: 11511364
```

Comment: Avoid running your app on emulator use real device!

Comment: Mr. Patel that is a real device ... Connected via USB cable .. not emulator